# Suzanize it! - Challenge #1

Tags: discussion, contest

If you haven't already, read [this Uncyclopedia article about Blender](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Blender#Cult_of_Noob).

## Contest: The Level One Beginner

Just about everyone has been there - the Level One Beginner; And if you haven't you probably know about someone who has. There was a time at the start, when you first opened Blender, probably, when you would praise the Suzanne deity. It's time to go back to that; Not quite, but still...

**Objective:**
Create an artwork whose main subject is the default Suzanne.

You can use any method you want, as long as you use only Blender, and keep at least something that resembles the default Suzanne.

**Rules:**

- Only *new and original* work
- Blender only, non commercial add-ons are allowed
- Keep it nice, nothing you wouldn't want to show to a five year old.
- Include .blend file, so we can be sure it is yours (use [pasteall.org](http://pasteall.org/blend))
- The competition runs for a week, you can edit/change your submission at anytime
- Late entries will be disqualified
- Only one entry per person
- Downvotes will not be considered when picking the winner

**Voting guide:**

<sup>(Going beyond the simple visual appeal)</sup>

1. Meets objective, not missing anything
2. No rules were broken
3. Artistically sound:

   - [Good composition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8i7OKbWmRM)
   - [Good use of color](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qj1FK8n7WgY)
   - Solid [design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design)
4. Humor:

   - Makes you laugh
   - has clever Easter eggs/references
5. Well Executed

   - Technically impressive
   - Quality of execution meets artistic goals.

**Winning criteria:**
Submission with the **most upvotes** as of November 23<sup>th</sup> 2014. The submission must to be posted before the deadline.

**Deadline: November 21<sup>st</sup> 2014 at UTC +0000**

## And most importantly, have fun!

**Final Results:**

1. [X-27](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/531/3127)
2. [gandalf3](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/534/3127) (First place for animation)
3. [stacker](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/532/3127)
4. [David](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/533/3127)
5. [someonewithpc](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/530/3127)

Comment: Seeing how many people commented on the other post asking for this, I hope as many are willing to get involved and take this seriously. Good luck to all participating. For any discussions or to share ideas, use the room [_Events_](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18173/events).

Comment: Regarding the "voting guidelines", I think I must have a different definition of "subjective".. See my comments in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18617832#18617832)

Comment: Please ask others one [Events](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18173/events?cb=1) before making edits... Especially later into the competition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My entree. Behold the flying fortress of total monkey awesomeness.
click on it for higher resolution
[image]

Comment: That is pretty sweet!

Comment: You now get to pick the next Contest's theme!

Comment: You can't really see it from that picture, but there are duel missile pods on the top that fire misses that can easily cross the ocean.<--(C#16)

Answer (score 10):

## The Endless Cycle of Suzanne

[image]

(click for a nice [html5 video version](http://gfycat.com/HarmfulSlowFish))

Comment: A very unique approach!

Comment: Wow, I love this, would have been awesome if the entire thing were Suzannes, leaves etc. ;)

Comment: @iKlsR Haha, thanks. That is an interesting idea.. Though Suzanne isn't very leaf-shaped :P The orange part of the flower is made entirely of Suzannes (just in case they are too small to see in the render..). I also tried to do a subtle blender logo reference, I'd be curious to know if anyone spots it ;)

Comment: @gandalf3 I saw, I was thinking of this image when I commented http://www.artstation.com/artwork/morning-snow. The snow is made from monkeys.

Comment: @iKlsR Wow, that is some realistic snow. I think I could mistake that for a photograph :)

Answer (score 7):

## NOTICE: To late to qualify

## The Fruit of the Noob: The Suzanne Apple.

*(Old cult of noob theme tie in)*

[image]

Fast fact, monkey fruit trees are a [real thing](http://www.pbase.com/image/121178393).

Eating the Suzanne Apple is believed to give the power of rembering keyboard shortcuts, not that it helps since they are random.

> especially as keys can change function depending on where the mouse is, what platform you are running it on, the day of the week, and the random movements of a quark someplace in the center of the Universe.
>   - [Blender page on Uncyclopedia](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Blender#Target_Audience)

Comment: Behold- I have brought forth a monkey!   :-)

Answer (score 4):

Behold, the Suzanne deity!! :D

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Missing nose

[image]

[.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/32963)

Comment: I like the concept! Not so much the composition though...

Answer (score 3):

A LEGO monkey, named Suzanne
<sub>click for full resolution (it really does have the LEGO bumps)</sub>
[image: LEGO suzanne]

Comment: Wow, that is *detailed*! Interesting choice of background/lighting though..

Comment: Excellent detail! I would be extremely interested in knowing how to do that! +1

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise remesh set to bricks, then replace every brick with a block..

Comment: @RadishoftheOpera that is not how I did it. I have said in chat before, but if you would like to know I will be happy to tell you.

Comment: Link???????????